# Using socket to cmmunicate node app to c# service

Tags: sockets, tcp, socket.io, tcpclient, tcplistener

[Sorry for my bad English]

Hi!

I have to communicate between a node.js application [client side] and c# application [server side].

Each side sends pings to the other, on TCP protocol.

I Successed to create both client and server side, but I have to problems:

1. after the first ping from the client to the server, the client throws an error:

> This socket has been ended by the other party
> What i'm doing wrong?

2. The server reads the incomeing pings into a large buffer.
   When I decode it to string, I get string with length of 4096.
   How I read the excact message length?

This is the server side code: [c#, .NET 6]

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

Console.WriteLine("Start...");

CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
TcpListener listener = new(IPAddress.Any, 11111);

try
{
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listining...");

    var clientCounter = 0;
    var ct = cts.Token;

    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        using TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(ct)
                                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        _ = PrintUploadedData(stream, ct);
        _ = PushData(stream, ct);

        clientCounter++;
        Console.WriteLine("New client ({0}) connected", clientCounter);
    }
}
finally
{
    cts.Cancel();
    listener.Stop();
}


async Task PrintUploadedData(NetworkStream stream, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var buf = new byte[4096];

    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var timeout = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
            ct, 
            new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)).Token);

        try
        {
            var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, timeout.Token);

            if (timeout.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("No Message.");
                break;
            }

            if (amountRead == 0) break; //end of stream.

            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Time out");
            break;
        }
    }
}

async Task PushData(NetworkStream stream, CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var messageToSend = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageToSend);

        await stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), ct);
    }
}
```

And the client side code [node.js]:

```js
import { Socket } from 'net';

var client = new Socket();

client.on('connect', () => console.log("CONNECTED"));
client.on('data', data => console.log("data", data.toString()));
client.on('error', err => console.error(err));

client.connect(11111, "127.0.0.1");

printMessages();

async function printMessages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        client.write('Ping ' + i);
        await sleep(4000);
    }
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: When you "call" async functions without wait you actually schedule theirs execution so message "New client ({0}) connected" most likely is printed prior execution of the bodies of PrintUploadedData and PushData. my bet is client goes out of scope and connection gets terminated. And corresponding stream gets closed while async tasks are still executed or even did not start theirs execution. try to pass client var as third parameter into async function to prolong its lifetime

Comment: I strongly recommend using an established standard like websockets rather than inventing your own protocol.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I must use socket, because the real application communcates with a some hardware controller, that uses socket.
But I found a solution similar to yours: using a library that does the job. I chose `SuperSimpleTcp` for server side, and `socket.io` for client side.